# AngularJs - including directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In our application we have app.js and the high level content is below.

```
 var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', ui.bootstrap', 'infinite-scroll']).config(function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
     });

      var appEmail = angular.module('testAppEmail', ['mnpi', 'ngTagsInput',     'ui.tinymce']);
```

This app.js is been included in all the html files.

I would like to include treeGrid in one of the html, say treeTest.html, hence, added tree-grid-directive.js in the treeTest.html.

We have a separate js (treeTest.js) for this html file.

treeTest.html,

```
<html ng-app='testApp'>

<script src='js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<script src="js/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs/tree-grid-directive.js"></script>

<script src="js/test/controllers/treeTest.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="treeTestCtrl">

 <div ng-if="loadingIsDone">
            <tree-grid tree-data="tree_data" 
                  tree-control="my_tree" 
                  col-defs="col_defs" 
                  expand-on="expanding_property" 
                  on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" 
                  expand-level="1" 
                  icon-leaf= "">
              </tree-grid>
              </div>
```

In treeTest.js,

```
angular.module('testApp').controller(

//app.controller(
        'treeTestCtrl',
        function($scope, $location, $http, $modal, $log, $window,
                referenceDataService, windowService, dealDataService) {

//     loading data for the tree and set the JSON array for the tree
}
```

Now, treeGrid works fine if i include the treeGrid directive in app.js as below.

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'infinite-scroll','treeGird']).config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

But the problem is, since it is added to app.js, it is expected to include the tree-grid-directive.js in all the pages.
Is there any way, I can include the treeGrid directive without adding in app.js so that I dont have to include the tree-grid-directive.js in all the pages.

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can let the array of dependencies be constructed dynamically, e.g.:

```
// additional dependencies here, this is the "dynamic part"
var dynamicDeps = ['treeGird'];

// common code
var deps = ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'infinite-scroll'];
angular.forEach(dynamicDeps, function(dep) {
    deps.push(dep);
});
var app = angular.module('testApp', deps).config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});

var appEmail = angular.module(...);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
But the common code is expected to load before the page specific js and I can not inject the treeGrid dynamic property from the testApp page to the common code.